# Website redirection according to location of a user

Tags: php

I have two websites for my organization.  One is for UK and another for India. I want to redirect Users to the particular websites based on their location, whether it is UK or India. In other words UK users to UK's website and India users to the Indian website keeping the URL same.

What are the possible solutions?

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title, or this question will be ignored by many people.

Comment: And everyone now in UK or India gets a blank page? IMO, automatic country redirects are a PITA. Google does them and I'm always annoyed by not being able to visit google.com.

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible solutions some of which include:

1. You could use the [GeoIP Apache Module](http://www.maxmind.com/app/mod_geoip) (`mod_geoip`) and `mod_rewrite`. You could either "proxy" the request, rewrite it internally, or change the directory where the files are retrieved from.
2. You could create snippet of code that you include in your `index.php` (or perhaps all of your pages) that load files from a different directory. PHP also includes functions (through [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/)) that use GeoIP data. [More information here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php).
3. You could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` as the country code is often coupled along with the language. I wouldn't recommend this method as it's very unreliable.
4. etc.

Comment: Option 3 is not viable, I'm a kiwi living in Brazil, I don't really speak Portuguese so 2 out of 3 OS's I use are in English and not Portuguese, my wife uses an English for her computer but she is Braizilian. I recommend the GeoIP or even the Google Geo Location API.

Comment: @Ryan - I couldn't agree more which is why I said that it's very unreliable (perhaps I should have bolded that). I just wanted to show that there are many way to achieve the result all of which may not be 100% accurate (we all know that IP-based location detection is not 100% accurate). Thanks for clarifying why option 3 is not a viable option.

Comment: Not a problem, I always think it helps when there is a real example behind the reasoning but when we answer we don't always have one

Answer (score 0):

You could analyze the HTTP header [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) sent by the browser and redirect accordingly, or use GeoIP, like Francois already mentioned.

But personally I'd always recommed to let the user decide himself where he wants to go.